# ruby strftime give wrong time

Tags: ruby, time

For Example, timestamp is `1403667010.574` , use `Time.at(1403667010.574).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L %z')`, then the resuit is

```
"2014-06-25 03:30:10.573 +0000"
```

it loss 1ms on the result. Is that a bug of ruby?

For me, the major problem is, if I convert the time string by `Time.parse("2014-06-25 03:30:10.573 +0000").to_f`, the result would become `1403667010.573`. It's not equivalent to origin value

Comment: No, it is not ruby's bug. It is **your** bug. Don't attribute your mistake to others. Be more humble.

Comment: Use Time.at(1403667010, 574000) could get more precise result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how floating point numbers work. They are approximately precise (not absolutely).

```
t = Time.at(1403667010.574)
t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L %z') # => "2014-06-25 07:30:10.573 +0400"

# more precision
t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%6N %z') # => "2014-06-25 07:30:10.573999 +0400"

# even more precision
t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%10N %z') # => "2014-06-25 07:30:10.5739998817 +0400"
```

In addition, this is what [Time#strftime documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Time.html#method-i-strftime) says about `%L` flag:

> **%L** - Millisecond of the second (000..999)
>          The digits under millisecond are truncated to not produce 1000.

So, the value `.573999` is simply truncated (not rounded) to `.573`

Comment: @sawa: without floating point precision part, it would be unclear where `".573999"` came from.

Comment: @ Sergio: I don't realize why the Time.parse("2014-06-25 03:30:10.573 +0000").usec can get correct floating point part ( 574000 ), but Time.at(1403667010.574).usec can't ( 573999 )

Comment: @Yehudi: if I were to find out about this, I'd go look at implementations of `Time.parse` and `Time.at`. Something is different. (at minimum, one accepts a string and the other - a number)